# Is contiguous memory allocation for variable guaranteed in c?

Tags: c, variables, memory

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 10, c = 2;
    int *arr[] = {&a, &b, &c}; 
    printf("%d\n", *arr[arr[1]-arr[0]]);
    return 0;
}
```

Here I am getting output `10`. By the output here I understand memory for the variable `a b c` continuous allocated. Is this output static or it depends on the system? Can I expect the same output in another system? And the contiguous memory allocation for these variable is guaranteed? Here I am using  gcc compiler.

Comment: No and no. The compiler is free to allocate it as it sees fit, as long as it satisfies the alignment requirements. It might even reorder these in the memory. Or optimize out completely.

Comment: There's no obligation to put these in memory at all until pointers get involved.

Comment: What do you mean by *`"this variable"`*?

Comment: A sequence of adjacent items is usually called "contiguous" not "continuous"

Comment: `int arr[] = {1, 10, 2};` `int *a = &arr[0], *b = &arr[1], *c = &arr[2];` `printf("%d\n", arr[b - a]);` may be a option

Comment: gcc with optimizations off causes the program to seg fault for me. So you can't even expect this program to work using the _same_ compiler on the _same_ system. That is the nature of undefined behavior bugs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`arr[1]-arr[0]` (which is `&b - &a`) makes your program have *undefined behavior* (UB).
Subtracting 2 pointers not from the same array (or 1 beyond) is UB.

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object;
> C2Xdr § 6.5.6 10

---

> Is continuous memory allocation for variable guaranteed in c?

No.

> Is this output static or it depends on the system?

No, it is UB.  The system may "work" as hoped sometimes and not others.

> Can I expect the same output in another system?

Another system may differ.  Even the same system may differ on different runs.

> And the continuous memory allocation for this variable is guaranteed?

No.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The UB "risk" about `arr[1]-arr[0]` is CYA. Had `arr[0] == arr[1]`, `arr[1]-arr[0]` is fine.  Of course if we step back to `&b - &a`, then yes, UB.

Answer (score 2):

> Is continuous memory allocation for variable guaranteed in c?

Space for any particular object is contiguous.  That includes aggregate objects (structures and arrays).

Otherwise, space for collections of distinct objects is not guaranteed to be contiguous, but it's pretty hard to check based solely on features defined by the language spec.  In particular, pointer differences such as your `arr[1]-arr[0]` are defined only for pointers into or just past the end of the same array.

> By the output here I understand memory for the variable `a b c` continuous allocated.

That's a plausible conclusion, but not one that can be supported based on the language spec alone.

> Is this output static or it depends on the system? Can I expect the same output in another system?

There is no basis in the language spec for concluding that you would see the same on another system, or even consistently on a given system.

> And the continuous memory allocation for this variable is guaranteed?

Absolutely not, except as already described.  And if you're writing code that depends on contiguous allocation under other circumstances then your code is dangerously wrong.

Comment: UV.  [danergous](https://www.state-machine.com/wp-content/uploads/fig2.jpg) to assume too much about memory.

Answer (score 1):

> And the continuous memory allocation for this variable is guaranteed?

Arrays.

C standard: 6.2.5

> An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of
> objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.

And it implies that object type has to be allocated in one memory block (so bytes from `int` cant be spread across the memory - and variable of type `int` will be stored in the contiguous memory chunk of size `sizeof(int)`).

But the order and place where different variables are stored is not specified by the standard, only their lifetime (storage duration).